# If statement works with [ but not with [[ when comparing strings with -eq

Tags: bash, test

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash

x=${#}

for (( a=0; a<x; ++a)); do
   if [[ $1 -eq $1 ]] 2> /dev/null
   then
      variable[a]=${1}
      shift
   else
      echo "The argument $1 is NOT an integer. Aborting this"
      exit 1
   fi
done
TOTAL=0
for (( a=0; a<x; ++a)); do
      echo "TOTAL : ${TOTAL}"
      TOTAL=$((TOTAL+variable[a]))
done
echo "Everything accounted to $TOTAL"
exit 0
```

So basically it takes the arguments of the script and sums them up. If one of the arguments is not an integer, it should tell you and exit the script.

The way it is right now it doesn't tell me if one of the arguments isn't an integer, it just skips it. So giving it the arguments 123 123 123 asdt, I get the following:

```
vagrant@localhost vagrant]$./super.sh 123 123 123 asdt
TOTAL : 0
TOTAL : 123
TOTAL : 246
TOTAL : 369
Everything accounted to 369
[07:43----------------------------------------
vagrant@localhost vagrant]$
```

But if I change it to this:

```
for (( a=0; a<x; ++a)); do
   if [ $1 -eq $1 ] 2> /dev/null
   then
```

It works and I get this:

```
vagrant@localhost vagrant]$./super.sh 123 123 123 asdt
The argument asdt is NOT an integer. Aborting this
[07:44----------------------------------------
vagrant@localhost vagrant]$
```

Why does that happen?

Comment: It's a fair question I think - see for example [How do I test if a variable is a number in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/808740/4440445) in particular the **CAVEATS**. Bottom line is you are relying on behavior that is unspecified in POSIX.

Comment: indeed, the test case here can be boiled down to `[[ asdt -eq asdt ]] && echo yes` versus `[ asdt -eq asdt ] && echo yes`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's one of the things how `[[ .. ]]` is special in Bash. `[[ a -eq b ]]` forces `a` and `b` to be taken as arithmetic expressions, and within one, a string is taken as the name of a variable. Other expressions works too, so you can do this:

```
$ a=2
$ [[ a -eq 1+1 ]] && echo yes
yes
```

On the other hand, `[` is an ordinary command, and obeys the same syntax as normal commands. It might even be implemented as an external binary. Here, `[` will just see `a`, and complain that it's not really an integer.

```
$ [ a -eq 2 ] && echo yes
bash: [: a: integer expression expected
$ /usr/bin/[ a -eq 2 ] && echo yes
/usr/bin/[: invalid integer ‘a’
```

Just use something like

```
a=asdf
if [[ $a = *[^0-9]* ]]; then
    echo "'$a' isn't an integer"
fi
```

or

```
a=asdf
case "$a" in 
    *[^0-9]*) echo "'$a' isn't an integer";;
esac
```

Apparently, `ksh` does the arithmetic evaluation of `a` and `1+1` even in `[ a -eq 1+1 ]`.

Comment: @Isaac, well well. Luckily for me, this was tagged Bash.